# ERROR: cluster.name is not a recognized option in elasticsearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I am trying to set up elasticsearch with python and as part of that I am trying to do a search from youtube data (as a sample).

I am using Windows 10 X64 machine with elasticsearch 6.5.4.

When I run the following command, I am getting an error

```
PS C:\Users\XXXXX\elasticsearch-6.5.4\bin> .\elasticsearch cluster.name=youtube node.name=video
starts elasticsearch

 - Option                Description
   ------                -----------

   -E <KeyValuePair>     Configure a setting

   -V, --version         Prints elasticsearch version information and exits

   -d, --daemonize       Starts Elasticsearch in the background

   -h, --help            show help

   -p, --pidfile <Path>  Creates a pid file in the specified path on start

   -q, --quiet           Turns off standard output/error streams logging in console

   -s, --silent          show minimal output

   -v, --verbose         show verbose output


ERROR: Positional arguments not allowed, found [cluster.name=youtube, node.name=video]
```

Comment: Seems you may just need to add `--` in front of `cluster.name` and `node.name`. But I'd need to know more about `elasticsearch` to be sure.

Answer (score 2):

It is mentioned in the usage/help info that you need to pass `-E` to set configurations:

> -E Configure a setting

It is also mentioned in their [Getting Started / Installation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/getting-started-install.html#successfully-running-node) steps:

> As mentioned previously, we can override either the cluster or node
>   name. This can be done from the command line when starting
>   Elasticsearch as follows:
>
> ```
> ./elasticsearch -Ecluster.name=my_cluster_name -Enode.name=my_node_name
> ```